# Create nested arrays from specific variables within session

Tags: php, arrays

I have several values stored in $_SESSION beginning with 'first_name_' & 'last_name_' which then a number appended to the end deepening on how many names are generated.

I am able to extract each of these values from the session and add to an array but would like to pair up the first and last names together within a nested array. (if that makes sense)

at the moment I have:

```
$users_array = array();

foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, 'first_name_') === 0) {
        $users_array[] = $value;            
}
    if(strpos($key, 'last_name_') === 0) {
        $users_array[] = $value;
    }
}
```

This produces an output with var_dump:

```
array
0 => string 'John' (length=4)
1 => string 'Smith' (length=8)
2 => string 'Jane' (length=4)
3 => string 'Doe' (length=3)
```

But what I would like is something  like:

```
array
'user' => 
    array
    'first_name' => string 'John' (length=4)
    'last_name' => string 'Smith' (length=5)
    array
    'first_name' => string 'Jane' (length=4)
    'last_name' => string 'Doe' (length=5)
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Why aren't they stored in that format in the session to begin with?

Comment: Not sure, this just seemed the easiest way to do what I wanted. It may be better to store them like that in the session, could you provide an example?

Comment: Uhm... `$_SESSION['users'][] = array('first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Doe')` when putting them into the session...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deceze is right in his comment... But just so people with similar issues with creating 2-dimensional array from a 1-dimensional array, here is a solution. Also, note that PHP does not guarantee that the order will be same when iterating using FOREACH. As this will work, it is still prone to errors.

```
$users_array = array();

foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, 'first_name_') === 0) {
        $users_array[] = array();
        $users_array[count($users_array)-1]['first_name'] = $value;         
}
    if(strpos($key, 'last_name_') === 0) {
        $users_array[count($users_array)-1]['last_name'] = $value;
    }
}
```